# Scrollbar appears during framer-motion animation?

Tags: reactjs, scrollbar, framer-motion

Bringing an image or a component from far off the side of the screen, into the screen via a variant like

```
const containerVariants = {
    hidden: {opacity : 0, x: '-100vw'},
    visible: {opacity : 1, x : 0}
  }
```

where initial is hidden and animate is visible, will result in the scrollbar appearing. I do not see the scrollbar appear on the tutorials I watch, any idea why this happens or how I can  prevent the scrollbar from appearing?
It seems counter-intuitive that a scrollbar would appear during framer motion as how else can I slide objects into view.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, resolved by removing "overflow: auto;" from css of the  container for my animated components.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to explicitly remove the scrollbars from appearing, you want to add `overflow: hidden;` to the style for that element and make sure there is a specified height.

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to the x value or y value you are giving for the hidden state. These values push the elements out of the normal width, and since when you scroll to it, you are not able to observe this behavior making it a real head scratcher. I personally found a work around for this by setting, width and height to 0 when hidden, and also overflow: hidden for the parent container.

```
    export function slideInFromLeft(delay: number) {
  return {
    hidden: { x: -1500, width: 0, height: 0, opacity: 0 },
    visible: {
      x: 0,
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      opacity: 1,
      transition: {
        delay: delay,
        duration: 0.5,
      },
    },
  };
}

export function slideInFromRight(delay: number) {
  return {
    hidden: { x: 1500, width: 0, height: 0, opacity: 0 },
    visible: {
      x: 0,
      width: "100%",
      height: "100%",
      opacity: 1,
      transition: {
        delay: delay,
        duration: 0.5,
      },
    },
  };
}
```

And for the parent container:

```
.parentContainer {
overflow: hidden
}
```